# How to check if href attribute contains a string?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anchor

I want to get all "a" tags from page, get its "href" attribute and check if in this href is text ".pdf". So I get all `a` tags into `tags` variable, then with `each()` function I check every "a" (as a `tag`). But code:

```
  if ($(tag).indexOf('.pdf') > 0) 
    console.log($(tag));
```

is not working. Why? Why I can't use `indexOf` on `href`? I tried with `search()` function, but it's also not working.

So I thought - ok, there's something wrong with this `href`. Lets take it as a text.

But code:

```
  var text = $(tag).text();
    console.log(text);
```

is also not working. Can anybody tell me why?

Code snippet has errors intentionally - to show with what I have a problem.

Thank you in advance.

```js
(function($){
  var tags = $('a');
  $(tags).each(function() {
        var tag = $(this).attr('href')     
        
        if ($(tag).indexOf('.pdf') > 0) 
          console.log($(tag));
            
        var text = $(tag).text();
        console.log(text);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <a href="https://www.test.com/example.pdf" target="_blank">Link with ".pdf"</a>
  <a href="https://www.test.com/" target="_blank">Link without ".pdf"</a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to for the additional `$(tag)` when calling indexOf. `tag` is a string at that point and you don't need to make it a jQuery object. simply call `tag.indexOf('.pdf') > 0`. For strings you can also use `tag.includes('.pdf')` or you go for `tag.substr(tag.length - 4, 4) === '.pdf'` to make it even more precise.